# Changing to a namespace that uses excludes

Tags: clojure

In a REPL, is there a way to change to a namespace in whose definition a core function is excluded, like

```
(ns bla (:refer-clojure :exclude [==]))
```

without having to retype the exclusion, like below?

```
user> (ns bla)
IllegalStateException == already refers to: #'clojure.core.logic/== in namespace: bla  clojure.lang.Namespace.warnOrFailOnReplace (Namespace.java:88)
user> (ns bla (:refer-clojure :exclude [==]))
nil
bla>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `in-ns`.  `ns` is primarily used to create a new namespace, while `in-ns` is primarily used to switch to an existing namespace.  Technically, both will create a new namespace if it doesn't exist already, but `in-ns` will not try to change the namespace if it already exists.

Comment: In case the namespace is not already loaded, he can `(doto 'blah require in-ns)`.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you already know that from emacs and using [CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider) you can Switch the namespace of the repl buffer to the namespace of the current buffer with this key binding

```
C-c M-n.
```

Of course you need first the clj file with the explicit namespace and exclusión defined